# LatentDirichletAllocation was not installed in decomposition module of SciKit-Learn

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I got some strange problem at SciKit-Learn package. 
There is "decomposition" module inside SciKit-Learn package, which should contain LatentDirichletAllocation([…]) function. See documentation here:
"https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.decomposition"

When I tried to import "decomposition" module: 
`from sklearn import as decomposition`
it gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_1_day_scikit_dnn.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sklearn import decomposition
  File "/home/developer1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._online_lda import LatentDirichletAllocation
ImportError: cannot import name 'LatentDirichletAllocation'
```

Command: 
`ls -al ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition` shows:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 developer1 developer1   4096 Dec  9 00:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 33 developer1 developer1   4096 Dec  9 00:45 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1   5490 Dec  9 00:44 _base.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    480 Dec  9 00:44 base.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 developer1 developer1 179440 Dec  9 00:44 _cdnmf_fast.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 developer1 developer1 175344 Dec  3 00:09 cdnmf_fast.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    498 Dec  9 00:44 cdnmf_fast.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1  54528 Dec  9 00:44 _dict_learning.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    507 Dec  9 00:44 dict_learning.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1  12572 Dec  9 00:44 _factor_analysis.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    513 Dec  9 00:44 factor_analysis.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1  20866 Dec  9 00:44 _fastica.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    490 Dec  9 00:44 fastica_.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1  14076 Dec  9 00:44 _incremental_pca.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    513 Dec  9 00:44 incremental_pca.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1   1401 Dec  9 00:44 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1  13597 Dec  9 00:44 _kernel_pca.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    498 Dec  9 00:44 kernel_pca.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1  47255 Dec  9 00:44 _nmf.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    477 Dec  9 00:44 nmf.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 developer1 developer1  62056 Dec  3 00:09 _online_lda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 developer1 developer1  62064 Dec  9 00:44 _online_lda_fast.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    513 Dec  9 00:44 online_lda_fast.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1  30471 Dec  9 00:44 _online_lda.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    498 Dec  9 00:44 online_lda.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1  22807 Dec  9 00:44 _pca.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    477 Dec  9 00:44 pca.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 developer1 developer1   4096 Dec  9 00:45 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    855 Dec  9 00:44 setup.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1  13654 Dec  9 00:44 _sparse_pca.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    498 Dec  9 00:44 sparse_pca.py
drwxr-xr-x  3 developer1 developer1   4096 Dec  9 00:45 tests
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1   8346 Dec  9 00:44 _truncated_svd.py
-rw-r--r--  1 developer1 developer1    507 Dec  9 00:44 truncated_svd.py
```

Most of the functions are here but there are no traces of the "LatentDirichletAllocation" function. Yet I did see LatentDirichletAllocation class defined in the _online_lda.py file.

Command `python3 -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()"` prints all versions required:

```
System:
    python: 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55)  [GCC 8.3.0]
executable: /usr/bin/python3
   machine: Linux-4.15.0-65-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic

Python dependencies:
       pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 42.0.2
   sklearn: 0.22
     numpy: 1.17.4
     scipy: 1.3.3
    Cython: None
    pandas: 0.25.3
matplotlib: 3.1.2
    joblib: 0.14.0

Built with OpenMP: True
```

So I assume all requirements were met here. (BTW SciKit-Learn worked fine till I tried to import "decomposition" module).

I installed the SciKit-Learn package as it was described here: 
"https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html"
using command `pip3 install -U scikit-learn`
I did reinstall that several times but got same result.

What do I do wrong? Do I need to add missing "LatentDirichletAllocation" function into the "decomposition" module? If so - how? Should I install the whole package somehow different way?

Thanks.

Comment: sklearn is broken in 0.22.. change it to 0.21.3 or lower

Comment: I did. See the "accepted answer" below. Still it would be great to have version 0.22 working too. It looks like "glemaitre" guy (see his answer) found workaround though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem today. I solved it by going back to the previous version 0.21 of scikit-learn:

```
pip3 install scikit-learn==0.21
```

EDIT: I think the answer from glemaitre (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59328446/10429267) shows a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... Still I hope there is some other fix for the problem.

Comment: Indeed this solved the problem - thank you again. That's not good that the newest 0.22 version is not usable though :(

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solved my problem as well. 
Curious to know if there any other alternative fix for the same?

Answer (score 3):

The validated "answered" is not the right fix since it only downgrades scikit-learn. You will not be able to benefit from new features and bug fixes.

It will be helpful instead to report and give feedback in the issue tracker: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15884

It will allow us to find the root of the problem and propose the proper fix which seems to affect several persons.

EDIT:
After some investigation, you need to remove the following files:

- `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/_online_lda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`
- `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`
- `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/_svmlight_format.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Apparently, the so files do not get removed when updating to scikit-learn. This might be due to an old `pip` version.

Comment: Indeed - the answer I accepted is valid is not the proper answer. But by the time it was the ONLY answer I got. With this answer I was able to use the SciKit-learn. it was my first experience with the SciKit learn and I was frustrated by this problem in latest version 0.22.

Comment: I am not entirely sure where should I remove `_online_lda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` - can you clarify please?

Comment: From the information that you gave, it should be located in: `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/_online_lda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: Note that there is a similar thing happening with the `FeatureHasher` which required to remove manually the `_hashing.cpython-*****.so` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

---

**For Python 3**

```
pip3 uninstall scikit-learn
pip3 install -U scikit-learn==0.21.3
```

---

**For Python 2**

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install -U scikit-learn==0.20.4
```

Comment: Version 0.22 is not broken and this is currently the last stable version. What is going wrong is the update of the package with a `pip` system.