# ImportError: cannot import name 'LatentDirichletAllocation'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, train-test-split

I'm trying to import the following:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

and got following error, here's the stack trace :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bdd2a2f20673> in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
----> 4 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
      5 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
      6 from sklearn import tree

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/tree/__init__.py in <module>
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from ._classes import BaseDecisionTree
      7 from ._classes import DecisionTreeClassifier
      8 from ._classes import DecisionTreeRegressor

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in <module>
     38 from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted
     39 
---> 40 from ._criterion import Criterion
     41 from ._splitter import Splitter
     42 from ._tree import DepthFirstTreeBuilder

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pxd in init sklearn.tree._criterion()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_tree.pxd in init sklearn.tree._splitter()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_quad_tree.pxd in init sklearn.tree._tree()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/__init__.py in <module>
     15 from ._kde import KernelDensity
     16 from ._lof import LocalOutlierFactor
---> 17 from ._nca import NeighborhoodComponentsAnalysis
     18 from ._base import VALID_METRICS, VALID_METRICS_SPARSE
     19 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_nca.py in <module>
     20 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
     21 from ..preprocessing import LabelEncoder
---> 22 from ..decomposition import PCA
     23 from ..utils.multiclass import check_classification_targets
     24 from ..utils.random import check_random_state

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/__init__.py in <module>
     17 from ._factor_analysis import FactorAnalysis
     18 from ..utils.extmath import randomized_svd
---> 19 from ._online_lda import LatentDirichletAllocation
     20 
     21 __all__ = ['DictionaryLearning',

ImportError: cannot import name 'LatentDirichletAllocation'
```

Actually I was trying to import :

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

Which gave me following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9ebede864c4d> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
      4 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
      5 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'
```

So, as answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667525/importerror-no-module-named-sklearn-cross-validation) post, I used `sklearn.model_selection` instead of `sklearn.cross_validation`. But it's still giving an error.

I'm using python 3.6.8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330970/5025009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is broken in 0.22 version**

Use stable versions:

**For Python 2**

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install -U scikit-learn==0.20.4
```

**For Python 3**

```
pip3 uninstall scikit-learn
pip3 install -U scikit-learn==0.21.3
```

Comment: I've already gone through enough answers and figured out it and updated sklearn to version = '0.22' and still getting an error so I've posted it here.

Comment: Nope. Why I need Conda? I'm not using such a vast set of libraries yet. My setup is just using jupyter notebooks and install required libraries manually.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll check it as soon as I work on this program again. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to an old `pip` version. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59328446/6513708

But long story short, you need to remove the following files which were let by `pip` during the update:

- `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/_online_lda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`
- `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: I deleted those files and then I started getting an error about some other module missing... tho the answer above by  @makis worked for me... thanks :)

Comment: Could you please report the error via the issue tracker: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15884. Downgrading the version of the scikit-learn is not a viable solution since 0.22 is the *last stable* version. The issue is not with the package itself but the package manager `pip`.

Having additional feedback will give us more info to solve this install issue for other users.