# ImportError: cannot import name 'LatentDirichletAllocation' when importing PCA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I keep getting the error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'LatentDirichletAllocation'`

full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/path/to/file/pca.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._online_lda import LatentDirichletAllocation
ImportError: cannot import name 'LatentDirichletAllocation'
```

when I try to import PCA using:

`sklearn.decomposition import PCA`

I deleted the sklearn folder and still get the error.

Comment: what' your sklearn version? `sklearn.__version__`

Comment: the version is 0.22

Comment: this is broken on 0.22 .. I have the same problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'LatentDirichletAllocation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59320664/importerror-cannot-import-name-latentdirichletallocation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broken installation.

Try:

**For Python 2**

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install -U scikit-learn==0.20.4
```

**For Python 3**

```
pip3 uninstall scikit-learn
pip3 install -U scikit-learn==0.21.3
```

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem, fully uninstalling and re-installing `scikit-learn` via `pip` fixed it.